# How to set value for dynamically generated form using angular 4

Tags: angular

I have angular 4 form which is generated dynamically using the configuration(JSON) file. And i want to set the value for input field while choosing the selectbox option.

I have created the sample code in `stackblitz`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnhcd1?file=src/app/dynamic-form-component.ts

Comment: You can format the FormGroup using a setter in @ Input https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to set the value.

```
this.issuerConfigForm.controls['iinprefix'].patchValue("20");
```

Comment: Use `setValue`, not `patchValue`

Comment: @Envil setValue is used for to set the value of all fields of form and patchValue is used for to set the value of specific field in form. Here vishnu just wanted to set the value of one field

Comment: @ParthSavadiya is it? https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value